# Captcha on a PHP form it shows error that your captcha is incorrect whenever anyones fill this form

Tags: php, forms, validation

this is my form as it sents the email to the four different email on selectoin of different radio buttons.....But i donot want the form to be submitted until the captcha is verified..so i added this captcha but it is not working I dont know why.Please help me on this... .Thanks in advance.

```
                <?php
                session_start();
                //error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

                //echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($_REQUEST);
                if(!empty($_POST['answer']) )
                {
                    //echo "You entered " . htmlentities($_POST['answer']) . " which is ";

                    if ($_SESSION['answer'] == $_POST['answer'])
                    {
                        //echo 'correct';
                        $validatedCaptcha = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<center>'.'You Filled wrong Captcha. We expected ' . $_SESSION['answer'].'      .Kindly Fill the Form Again'.'</center>';
                        $validatedCaptcha = false;
                    }
                }

                $digit1 = mt_rand(1, 20);
                $digit2 = mt_rand(1, 20);
                if (mt_rand(0, 1) === 1) {
                    $math = "$digit1 + $digit2";
                    $_SESSION['answer'] = $digit1 + $digit2;
                } else {
                    if($digit1 >= $digit2)
                    {
                        $math = "$digit1 - $digit2";    
                        $_SESSION['answer'] = $digit1 - $digit2;
                    }
                    else if($digit1 < $digit2)
                    {
                        $math = "$digit2 - $digit1";    
                        $_SESSION['answer'] = $digit2 - $digit1;
                    }
                }
                //echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($_SESSION);
                ?>
                <center>
                    <?php
                    $name = $_REQUEST['name11'];
                    $email = $_REQUEST['email11'];
                    $phone12 = $_REQUEST['mobile11'];
                    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject11'];
                    $message1 = $_REQUEST['message11'];
                    $zone1 = $_REQUEST['zone1'];
                    $null_virdi = "-f " . $email;


                    if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $validatedCaptcha == true ) {

                        $message = "Name: " . $name . "\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\n" . "phone :" . $phone12 . "\n" . "Message :" . $message1;

                        if ($_REQUEST['zone1'] == "South") {

                            echo "Thank you for Contacting our South Indian Zonal Office";
                            mail("abc@gmail.com", $subject, $message, null, $null_virdi);
                        }

                        if ($_REQUEST['zone1'] == "Delhi") {

                            mail("abc@gmail.com", $subject, $message, null, $null_virdi);
                            echo "Thank you for Contacting our Delhi Office";
                        }

                        if ($_REQUEST['zone1'] == "Hyderabad") {

                            mail("abc3@gmail.com", $subject, $message, null, $null_virdi);
                            echo "Thank you for Contacting our Hyderabad & AP Office";
                        }

                        if ($_REQUEST['zone1'] == "Pune") {

                            mail("abc4@gmail.com", $subject, $message, null, $null_virdi);
                            echo "Thank you for Contacting our Pune/Nasik Office";
                        }

                        if ($_REQUEST['zone1'] == "west") {

                            mail("abc5@gmail.com", $subject, $message, null, $null_virdi);
                            echo "Thank you for Contacting our West Zone Office";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <html><head>
                            <script>
                                function validateForm()
                                {
                                    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email1"].value;
                                    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
                                    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
                                    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length)
                                    {
                                        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>
                        </head><body>

                           <div style="width:50%;border: 4px double #dbd395;margin: 0;padding: 28px 0px 0px 34px;background-color: #F8F8F8">   
                 <form name="myForm" action="" onSubmit="return validateForm();" method="post" >

                             <table >
                                    <tr>
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:5px;">Enquiry for Quotation</h3>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Name&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" required="required" name="name11"  size="40"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Email&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" required="required" name="email11" size="40"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Mobile&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" required="required" name="mobile11" size="40"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Zone&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;<input type="radio" required="required" name="zone1" value="South"/>South India &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="zone1" value="Delhi" />Delhi NCR <input type="radio" name="zone1" value="Hyderabad"/>Hyderabad & AP <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="zone1" value="Pune"/>Pune/Nashik <input type="radio" name="zone1" value="west"/>Other </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Subject&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" required="required" name="subject11" size="40"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: top;"><font style=vertical-align:top; color="#000000">Message</font><font style=vertical-align:top; color="#FF0000">* :</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea rows="4" cols="32" name="message11" required="required"/></textarea></td>
                                    </tr>
                <tr><td><center><b>Captcha</b></center></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td align="center">What's <?php echo $math; ?> = <input size="5" name="answer" type="text" /><br /></td></tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">


                                            <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message"/></td>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>

                            </form>
                </div>
                        <body/>
                    </html>
                </center>
```

Comment: Start by removing `</center>` after `</html>` and re-enabling error reporting.

Comment: We don't know either, since you haven't explained at all HOW this script isn't working.

Comment: he's checking the math serverside but not doing anything afterwards if the check fails besides `$validCaptcha = false;` and he's not checking the math at all client side. So: works as designed ... ;-). NTL: this kind of "captcha" will usually be broken by a brute force, simply posting all numbers between 1 and 1,000 against the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "captcha" is totally weak: the "answer" is a value between (1+1) and (20+20), giving a number of not more than 39 different results in a consecutive row (2...40).

As there are parsers out there (and I've seen them working on various forms with "captchas" like this) which just simply brute force post random numbers from 1...100 against forms like this, it will take them a couple of minutes to post/register/whatever to your site.

Comment: but whenever anyone fills the form the error comes you have filled wrong captcha.....why is that...?

Answer (score 0):

Well i didnt get the proper answer i asked for...but the problem was i was using this form in the wordpress page and it was not working as captcha validation always went wrong and form always used to echo that your captcha is wrong that is present in the else part. But after doing some research i found that problem was due to session which I was using in my form I have got to know that wordpress has its own session so validation will always come wrong. so i did this and My form is working now. Hope it will  help anybody else also.

```
        <?php  //error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);  ?>
        <?php

        if(!empty($_POST['answer']) )
        {
            //echo "You entered " . htmlentities($_POST['answer']) . " which is ";

            if ($_REQUEST['answer'] == $_POST['answer'])
            {
                //echo 'correct';
                $validatedCaptcha = true;
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<center>'.'You Filled wrong Captcha. We expected ' . $_REQUEST['answer'].'      .Kindly Fill the Form Again'.'</center>';
                $validatedCaptcha = false;
            }
        }

        $digit1 = mt_rand(1, 20);
        $digit2 = mt_rand(1, 20);
        if (mt_rand(0, 1) === 1) {
            $math = "$digit1 + $digit2";
            $_REQUEST['answer'] = $digit1 + $digit2;
        } else {
            if($digit1 >= $digit2)
            {
                $math = "$digit1 - $digit2";    
                $_REQUEST['answer'] = $digit1 - $digit2;
            }
            else if($digit1 < $digit2)
            {
                $math = "$digit2 - $digit1";    
                $_REQUEST['answer'] = $digit2 - $digit1;
            }
        }
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($_SESSION);
        ?>
        <center>
            <?php
            $name = $_REQUEST['name11'];
            $email = $_REQUEST['email11'];
            $phone12 = $_REQUEST['mobile11'];
            $subject = $_REQUEST['subject11'];
            $message1 = $_REQUEST['message11'];
            $zone1 = $_REQUEST['zone1'];
            $null_virdi = "-f " . $email;


            if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $validatedCaptcha == true ) {

                $message = "Name: " . $name . "\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\n" . "phone :" . $phone12 . "\n" . "Message :" . $message1;

                if ($_REQUEST['zone1'] == "South") {

                    echo "Thank you for Contacting our South Indian Zonal Office";
                    mail("blrbranch@sonatech.net", $subject, $message, null, $null_virdi);
                }

                if ($_REQUEST['zone1'] == "Delhi") {

                    mail("sales@sonatech.net", $subject, $message, null, $null_virdi);
                    echo "Thank you for Contacting our Delhi Office";
                }

                if ($_REQUEST['zone1'] == "Hyderabad") {

                    mail("chandel@sonatech.net", $subject, $message, null, $null_virdi);
                    echo "Thank you for Contacting our Hyderabad & AP Office";
                }

                if ($_REQUEST['zone1'] == "Pune") {

                    mail("manjot@hitechwebsolutions.in,pankaj@sonatech.net", $subject, $message, null, $null_virdi);
                    echo "Thank you for Contacting our Pune/Nasik Office";
                }

                if ($_REQUEST['zone1'] == "west") {

                    mail("sales@sonatech.net", $subject, $message, null, $null_virdi);
                    echo "Thank you for Contacting our West Zone Office";
                }
            }
            ?>
            <html><head>
                    <script>
                        function validateForm()
                        {
                            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email1"].value;
                            var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
                            var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
                            if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length)
                            {
                                alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                </head><body>

                   <div style="width:50%;border: 4px double #dbd395;margin: 0;padding: 28px 0px 0px 34px;background-color: #F8F8F8">   
         <form name="myForm" action="" onSubmit="return validateForm();" method="post" >

                     <table >
                            <tr>
                            <h3 style="margin-left:5px;">Enquiry for Quotation</h3>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" required="required" name="name11"  size="40"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" required="required" name="email11" size="40"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Mobile&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" required="required" name="mobile11" size="40"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Zone&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;<input type="radio" required="required" name="zone1" value="South"/>South India &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="zone1" value="Delhi" />Delhi NCR <input type="radio" name="zone1" value="Hyderabad"/>Hyderabad & AP <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="zone1" value="Pune"/>Pune/Nashik <input type="radio" name="zone1" value="west"/>Other </td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Subject&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" required="required" name="subject11" size="40"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align: top;"><font style=vertical-align:top; color="#000000">Message</font><font style=vertical-align:top; color="#FF0000">* :</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea rows="4" cols="32" name="message11" required="required"/></textarea></td>
                            </tr>
        <tr><td><center><b>Captcha</b></center></td></tr>
                            <tr><td align="center">What's <?php echo $math; ?> = <input size="5" name="answer" type="text" /><br /></td></tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">


                                    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message"/></td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                    </form>
        </div>
                <body/>
            </html>
        </center>
```

Comment: Someone above said to me to remove center tag from the code that is why it is not working..But i say it is working fine. Rest is your choice